# What's the difference between passing express middlewares individually and as an array?

Tags: typescript, express, validation, middleware, zod

I ran into an interesting problem when trying to validate request params with [zod-express-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod-express-middleware). The problem can be recreated with these two simple files:

`middleware.ts`

```js
import express from 'express';

export const myMiddleware = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    next()
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

`router.ts`

```js
import { Router } from "express";
import { myMiddleware } from "./randomMw";
import { validateRequest } from "zod-express-middleware";
import { z } from 'zod';

const RequestBody = z.object({
  one: z.string(),
  two: z.number()
})

const myRouter = Router()

myRouter.post("/",
  myMiddleware,
  validateRequest({ body: RequestBody }),
  async (req, res) => {
    const { one, two } = req.body
    console.log(one, two)
    res.sendStatus(200)
  }
)
```

And the relevant packages being

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "zod": "^3.18.0",
    "zod-express-middleware": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
  }
```

If used like above, the types will be inferred correctly when destructuring. However, if the middlewares are given as any kind of array the types will be lost at the actual request handler.

```js
// First
myRouter.post("/",
  [myMiddleware],
  validateRequest({ body: RequestBody }),
  async (req, res) => {
    const { one, two } = req.body
    console.log(one, two)
    res.sendStatus(200)
  }
)

// Second
myRouter.post("/",
  [
   myMiddleware,
   validateRequest({ body: RequestBody })
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const { one, two } = req.body
    console.log(one, two)
    res.sendStatus(200)
  }
)

// Third
myRouter.post("/",
  [
   myMiddleware,
   validateRequest({ body: RequestBody }),
   async (req, res) => {
     const { one, two } = req.body
     console.log(one, two)
     res.sendStatus(200)
   }
  ]
)
```

My question is that what's the difference between passing the middlewares as an array and individually? Does something happen there? I have been checking the source code from the `zod-express-middleware`, but can't see anything in there that would cause the issue and I assume something happens when giving the middlewares as an array.

Comment: Harder to do the inference correctly when it's given as a single array. That's it.

Comment: How come it's harder to do? Aren't the middlewares run in the given order anyway after each other even when given as an array?

Comment: Yes, but that's runtime. It's just harder to make the inference work without resorting to a million overloads. What kind of answer are you expecting? I can't really demonstrate something that I can't do. Within the best of my abilities, it is impossible to do the inference with an array.

Comment: I wasn't expecting any specific answer. I just didn't understand what you meant at first. But then what I still don't understand is that the validation middleware is the last middleware in the chain and not in the middleware array, so I don't understand why the inference fails after that one and the types are not shown correctly in the request handler.